# Need to update the Date format on my Google Mail Script

Tags: date, format, gmail-api

I'm creating a Gmail script that includes 5 variables, one of which is a due date. I just want it to populate as MM/DD/YYYY, however, it is currently populating as Thu Sep 13 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT).

Is there a way I can do that? I've pasted my code below for your reference. Any assistance is much appreciated.

```
    function getRowsData(sheet, range, columnHeadersRowIndex) {
  columnHeadersRowIndex = columnHeadersRowIndex || range.getRowIndex() - 1;
  var numColumns = range.getEndColumn() - range.getColumn() + 1;
  var headersRange = sheet.getRange(columnHeadersRowIndex, range.getColumn(), 1, numColumns);
  var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
  return getObjects(range.getValues(), normalizeHeaders(headers));
}

function getObjects(data, keys) {
  var objects = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var object = {};
    var hasData = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) {
      var cellData = data[i][j];
      if (isCellEmpty(cellData)) {
        continue;
      }
      object[keys[j]] = cellData;
      hasData = true;
    }
    if (hasData) {
      objects.push(object);
    }
  }
  return objects;
}

function normalizeHeaders(headers) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i) {
    var key = normalizeHeader(headers[i]);
    if (key.length > 0) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
  }
  return keys;
}


function normalizeHeader(header) {
  var key = "";
  var upperCase = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < header.length; ++i) {
    var letter = header[i];
    if (letter == " " && key.length > 0) {
      upperCase = true;
      continue;
    }
    if (!isAlnum(letter)) {
      continue;
    }
    if (key.length == 0 && isDigit(letter)) {
      continue; 
    }
    if (upperCase) {
      upperCase = false;
      key += letter.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      key += letter.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  return key;
}
function isCellEmpty(cellData) {
  return typeof(cellData) == "string" && cellData == "";
}

function isAlnum(char) {
  return char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z' ||
    char >= 'a' && char <= 'z' ||
    isDigit(char);
}

function isDigit(char) {
  return char >= '0' && char <= '9';
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to isolate it down to where you assign the date you're referring to, and also where you output the date later on?  This should be a simple case of DT formatting, but I'm having trouble isolating where you pull in, and later on, utilize the DateTime in question.

Comment: I made the required edits.